# What are the functions of these set of components in this push-pull converter (DC/DC converter for step-up of battery voltage) of a 220V 1kVA UPS?

Tags: circuit-design, filter

Push-pull converter:
[image]

Controller circuit for the push-pull converter:
[image]

What is the role of the highlighted components in this circuit?

Comment: I'm not sure Q2 and Q4 are shown the correct way round

Comment: @Neil_UK Yea, you're right. Q2 and Q4 are connected the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

1. C1-C4 are to maintain a clean 12V to local circuitry. They won’t help with common mode conducted emissions. They will help with differential mode noise toward the battery, if that is an issue.
2. The circuitry around the inductor is a pre charge for C6,C7 to prevent L1 from saturating on power up and may help as transient clamp once C5 is charged. My first thought, snubber, but not certain.
3. The resistor R10 in series with the BJT base limit the current draw from the pwm chip. Then the parallel capacitor is a speed-up to compensate.
4. C8 is a local energy store to provide a high current to charge all those parallel gates quickly. It bypasses power supply wire inductance.

Comment: Sorry for the last response, I've posted this question last night and had university in the morning. I pretty much get everything except "may help as transient clamp once C5 is charged". Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I have another question as well. You said the circuitry around the inductor is to prevent L1 from saturating during power up, and this is a problem because If the inductor were to saturate, it would cause a precipitous drop in the inductor's impedance and a significant increase in current which could potentially damage the inductor and other components in the circuit, right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's part of the answer.

C1, C2, C3, & C4 are probably an EMI filter, for conducted emissions.  Though I would have expected to see a common mode choke there someplace.

Do you know what the switching frequency of the half bridge is?

D17, R13, R16 (etc) is where I would expect to see a bleed path for the high voltage, to discharge the output caps when the PS is turned off.  But that's not what these components do.  So I'm not sure what they're supposed to do.

C6 & C7 are to help speed up the turn on & turn off of Q1-Q4 by bypassing R10 & R11.

Comment: Possibly snubbing for diode switching at L1?

Comment: Agree.  Snubber was going to be my guess also, but I didn't include that because it was a guess.

Comment: Sorry for the last response. I posted this question last night and had university in the morning. You said that C6 & C7 help speed up the turning on & off of Q1 to Q4, and while I understand how it can speed up turning off, I'm unclear about how it speeds up turning on. My understanding of how it can speed up turning off is from [here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/resistor-and-capacitor-on-mosfet-gate/).